# Bookmarks grouping in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

It seems there is only one list of bookmarks in PyCharm. Is there any way (that I missed) to group bookmarks, e.g. in folders such that each folder contains bookmarks from a given file. Is it possible to do in PyCharm?